# image is not loading , .htaccess file problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Someone tell me, where i'm doing wrong . this is my .htaccess file code

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Core/index.php?app=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here everything looks good. every request go to Core/index.php file. but when I type a URL to any file ( images, video ...) which is in current server, then file is not loading in browser. instead of file loading , it loads index.php page again (I found in Network panel of the browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown attempts. You should write rule of removing `/` at last before your other rule of rewriting.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Core/index.php?app=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: hey sir , I tried it but this time , it show me Access Forbidden Error 403 . I also tried it by commenting the Option-indexes , but this time it just show me file structure . All above  I tried in New Incognito window (private Window of the browser)

Comment: @AnujKumar, ok what happens if you comment `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]`(comment it by changing it to `##RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]` rule once? Let me know.

Comment: Same problem again

Comment: @AnujKumar, ok, where is your htaccess file located? It should be placed besides `Core` folder NOT inside `Core` folder, let me know where it is.

Comment: my file structure -> in the root ( `app folder, Core folder and a .htaccess file `), in the app folder(`theme files`), in the Core folder (`database folder, libraries folder, Config.php  file and index.php file `)

Comment: @AnujKumar, ok cool, so if you are hitting a link(non existing file or directory) what does it give you?

Comment: All the request (no existing or existing file or folder) goes to just  `Core/index.php` , And in this file I have made a basic html heading (testing perpose). So heading show me again and again.

Comment: @AnujKumar, ok rules are looking fine to me. Could you please put a line like `----------` in your htaccess file and try any URL of you get 500 internal error then it means its enabled else it's not enabled let me know how it goes? Cheers

Comment: I have placed `--------` before `Option-indexes` . This time , it is show me `Server error! ` *** Error 500 ***

Comment: @AnujKumar, Ok I have re-read your one of previous comments `All the request (no existing or existing file or folder) goes to just Core/index.php , And in this file I have made a basic html heading (testing perpose)` so that means correct right? I thought this is what you need? To redirect/rewrite all non existing requests to be served by index.php, OR there could be multiple index.php rewrites? Kindly clarify more on this one, thank you.

Comment: I don't how but this time everything working fine, I have used your code , thanks sir

Comment: @AnujKumar, May be its cache issue or so. Cheers and happy learning on this great site :) keep posting and keep learning

Comment: When searched `http://localhost` it show me error 403 but when I search like `http://localhost/anything` , Everything work  why ?  . I have uncomment that Rewrite line

Comment: @AnujKumar, ok `http://localhost` should be served by index,php file also? Kindly confirm once.